# Python Selenium Firefox - how to enable headless-mode as part of a class/object?

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, geckodriver

I have the following code:

```
options = Options()
options = options.set_headless( headless=True)

class Sel_Driver():

    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=options)
```

I can then use `self.driver.get(url)` as part of a method to open urls I feed in. This works - I can feed in and open the URLs, but they don't in headless mode.

(I initially defined the driver as `self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=Options().set_headless(headless=True)` - but that didn't work, so I tried it as above).

What am I missing? I don't understand why the driver is able to open pages, but the options aren't enabled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please try following code :

```
options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=options)
```

Comment: In newer versions i'm pretty sure you can also do `options.headless = True`.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you for sure. Try it.Please **specify the path of the driver.** It is for chrome change it to firefox.

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path="C:\\Users\\Username\\Downloads\\chromedriver.exe")
print("Firefox Headless Browser Invoked")
driver.get('https://www.facebook.com/')
jks = driver.find_element_by_id("email").get_attribute("class")
print(jks)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Thanks dude. I'm sure this would work, it's very similar to what I had previously. However, I tried putting it in the form of a class/object so that I wasn't instantiating a new webdriver for each url I want to open. As per the accepted answer, `options.add_argument("--headless")` does indeed fix the issue. Welcome to Stack Overflow =)